# Unable to conform to a protocol using another conforming protocol

Tags: swift

I came across the following code and am not sure why it doesn’t compile:

```swift
protocol CellDelegate: class {}

protocol DelegatingCellViewModel {
    var delegate: CellDelegate? { get }
}

protocol ProductCellViewModelDelegate: CellDelegate {}

// Error: Type 'ProductCellViewModel' does not conform to protocol 'DelegatingCellViewModel'
class ProductCellViewModel: DelegatingCellViewModel {
    weak var delegate: ProductCellViewModelDelegate?
}
```

Full error message:

```
error: Playground.playground:9:7: error: type 'ProductCellViewModel' does not conform to protocol 'DelegatingCellViewModel'
class ProductCellViewModel: DelegatingCellViewModel {
      ^

Playground.playground:10:14: note: candidate has non-matching type 'ProductCellViewModelDelegate?'
    weak var delegate: ProductCellViewModelDelegate?
             ^

Playground.playground:4:9: note: protocol requires property 'delegate' with type 'CellDelegate?'; do you want to add a stub?
    var delegate: CellDelegate? { get }
        ^
```

Is this a language limitation or am I missing something?
How should this code be written so it compiles and keeps the intent?

Comment: can you please post the exact error message?

Comment: @shivi_shub added

Comment: Maybe weak is the reason?

Comment: Actually the error messages are pretty descriptive.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha nope, it make no difference

Comment: @vadian any idea how to work around the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of delegate or add the protocol stubs.

```
class ProductCellViewModel: DelegatingCellViewModel {
    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
}
```

OR
you must change the name of that particular delegate like this. Because delegate name already used by conforming protocol -

```
class ProductCellViewModel: DelegatingCellViewModel {
    var delegate: CellDelegate?
    weak var productDelegate: ProductCellViewModelDelegate?
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach looses the more concrete delegate type `ProductCellViewModelDelegate`. Is there a way to write the code so I can keep it?

Comment: @NikitaKukushkin check the edited answer.